# getting selected option value from table row

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table in this table i have three select option. When I click on Güncelle button I want to get selected values of 3 select option. My  jquery and php codes are below:

**My php code is below:**

```
echo '<tr><td name="olurmu"><select class="bnci" name="birinci">
<option selected="selected"> .$rfirst"].</option>
   <option value="dogru">Doğru</option>
      <option value="yanlis">Yanlış</option>
         </selec"ikinci" >
             <option selected="selected">  '  .$rowecond"]. '</option>
                <option value="dogru">Doğru</option>
                 <option value="yanlis">Yanlış</option>
                 </select> </td><td><input type="button"  value="celle"   name="btn_updatele"  class/option>
  <option value="reddet">Reddet</option>     
</select></td></tr>'    ;
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in your php code

Comment: did you get any console error?

Comment: `</tr>"    ;` - as said; that will throw a parse error. You opened the statement with a single quote `echo '<tr>`.

Comment: </tr>' I edited it still problem is going on

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php 

echo '<tr><td name="olurmu"><select class="birinci" name="birinci">
<option selected="selected"> '.$row["satici_kargo_no_dogrumu"].'</option>
   <option value="dogru">Doğru</option>
      <option value="yanlis">Yanlış</option>
         </select> </td><td>  
           <select class="ikinci" name="ikinci" >
             <option selected="selected">  '  .$row["alici_kargo_no_dogrumu"]. '</option>
                <option value="dogru">Doğru</option>
                 <option value="yanlis">Yanlış</option>
                 </select> </td><td><input type="button"  value="Güncelle"   name="btn_updatele"  class="btn_update" data-id3="'.$row["paymentTransactionId"].'"  /> </td> <td>  
              <select class="ucuncu" name="ucuncu">
           <option selected="selected">  '  .$row["siparis_manuel_onay_durumu"]. '
        </option>
      <option value="beklemede">Beklemede</option>
    <option value="kabul et">Kabul et</option>
  <option value="reddet">Reddet</option>     
</select></td></tr>'    ;



?>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".btn_update").on("click",function(){
    alert("birinci: "+ $(".birinci").val() + " | ikinci: "+ $(".ikinci").val() +" | ucuncu: "+$(".ucuncu").val());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use the following**

**$('.ikinci').val();**

**$('.ucuncu').val();**